# "The following build commands failed: Ld...."

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I have been running into an issue while trying to build my app using either

```
yarn react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 14"
or 
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 14"
```

Error:
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
Ld /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname-hash/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Appname.app/Appname normal (in target 'Appname' from project 'Appname')
(1 failure)

I have tried a couple of things specifically in the order mentioned below

```
1-) Delete the Pods/, Podfile.lock, node_modules/, yarn.lock directories/files:
    rm -rf Pods/
    rm Podfile.lock
    rm -rf node_modules/
    rm yarn.lock
2-) Delete the Project Build Data and Indexes from your Mac's storage
3-) Clean cache in Xcode
4-) Clean cache with Yarn/npm
    yarn cache clean
    or
    npm cache clean --force
5-) Clean pod cache
    pod cache clean --all
6-) Install node modules
    yarn install
7-) Re-install pods
    pod install
```

Still, nothing seems to work at all.

```
Environment
macOS : 13.0.1
react-native: 0.64.2,
Xcode : 14.3
npm : 8.1.2 (Global)
```

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated as I have already spent a good amount of time trying to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem before on an old project with RN 0.64 while running on XCode 14.3. I did to solve the problem:

- cd ios
- pod deintegrate
- rm -rf Podfile.lock
- Open your `Podfile` add the following in the `post_install` phase (more less at the line 30)

```rb
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    # add this below
    installer.aggregate_targets.each do |aggregate_target|
      aggregate_target.user_project.native_targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS'] = ['$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift', '$(inherited)']
        end
      end
      aggregate_target.user_project.save
    end
  end
```

- Then run pod install
- And then build your project!

See more here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31941#issue-959300156

I hope it solves your problem!